# Metatag and page title modules conflict

Tags: hooks, meta-tags, 7

I am using Drupal 7 with the [Metatag](https://drupal.org/project/metatag) module along with the [Page title](https://drupal.org/project/page_title) module.

I have a requirement to build the title of a custom content type using some node fields and additional conditions that I can't reproduce using the tokens provided, so I have hooked to the page title API ( `hook_page_title_alter(&$title)`) to build my custom title only for one node type.

The function works and the page title is set. But the meta tags are wrong, they are not using the page title found in `<TITLE>` (under `<HEAD>`) but the node's title which I don't want to use.

How do I feed metatags module with my custom title ? I am out of ideas, so anything is appreciated.

As commented by someone you don't need the page_title module if you use metatags, but page_title provides an API with hooks to alter the page title, and that's what I am using and what I need to use, so maybe the question could be reformulated to "How do I alter the page title generated by metatags?"

Comment: There is already 'Page title' configuration with 'Meta tag' Module. You do not need to install separate 'Page title' module.

Comment: So the hooks already exist in the metatag module ? I will take a look.

Comment: The API hooks for altering the title are not present in the metatags module, so I need both. Or a hook elsewhere to modify the metatags title ...

Comment: Are you using Drupal 7?

Comment: Yes, Drupal 7 (edited).

Comment: If you edit you content, you will get 'Page title' under 'Meta tag' fieldset. You can use 'token' to set page title or can set pattern in 'Meta tag' under search metadata in admin.

Comment: I already know and use that, but my requirements for the title are quite unique and I need to set it using PHP.

Comment: OK. I have not looked into api of metatag. I will look into this and if I found anything, I will let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a bad idea to have both modules altering the page title. A better approach I have found is to create a [custom token](http://drupalcode.org/project/examples.git/blob/HEAD:/token_example/token_example.tokens.inc), (which is really trivial with the provided example) and use it inside a metatag configuration for the desired node type. This way [page_title](https://drupal.org/project/page_title) could be uninstalled since it's no longer needed.