# Page title - Token drupal 7 issue

Tags: 7, meta-tags

Shortly, here is my situation:

1. I have installed both [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) and [Page Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_title) modules.
2. The Page Title module page shows all my nodes and correspondent meta title I inserted.
3. The issue is that on certain pages (say Product page), meta title is
   not generated and it generates something like [node:field_zone_geo]
   instead of generating directly the Zone, say New York.

P.S. All other tokens are well generated within the meta titles, but this won't. Made lot of research and couldn't find any solution. I even de-installed the two modules (Metatag and Page Title) in order to avoid conflicts between them, but no solution.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90388/metatag-and-page-title-modules-conflict